# Stop React dev server while continuing parent script execution

Tags: reactjs, bash, powershell

I need a `test.sh` (bash)/`test.ps1` (powershell) shell script of the following structure:

```
<build preparation>
npx react-scripts start
<build cleanup>
```

The build cleanup step should run after I stop the localhost development server.

Currently, if I send Ctrl+C to the terminal, it stops both the dev server as well as the parent script, so the build cleanup step is not executed.

I did not find similar questions online (I am not sure what to search). Preferably, I need both PowerShell and Linux solutions. My only guess is somehow the react-scripts command should "trap" the shell Ctrl+C invocation, and self-exit safely, but I do not know how to do that unless react-scripts implements it on their own.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell you can use a [`try{}finally{}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally) construct to ensure the cleanup is run on interruption:

```
# <build preparation>
try {
  npx react-scripts start
}
finally {
  # <build cleanup>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this: ```  try {
    npx react-scripts start
  } finally {
    Write-Output "Exiting..."
    Write-Error "Exiting..."
    Write-Debug "Exiting..."
    Set-Content -Path 'newfile.txt' -Value "check"
  }``` but none of the four statements executed. I am using PS7 if it matters.